# How to Merge Select TFS Changesets into My Workspace without All Previous Changesets Included

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am working on a project with another developer.  We are in the process of a major upgrade with lots of breaking changes.  The software we are working on is an AddOn to a product, and we are upgrading to work with a new version of the product.  He has checked in some breaking changes that will not run in my environment yet because I am still running on the old version of the product.  I have checked in some changes on top of those.  Is there any way I can retrieve the code such that it includes only the changes up to the point before the breaking changes and also include only my changes after that in my workspace?

If I had not done a "get latest" I would be OK now because I made the changes on my machine so I would have them.  But now I need to "get specific version" to take me back before all the breaking changes and somehow merge only my changesets into my workspace.  But there seems to be no way to merge changesets into a workspace, only into another tree.  I could select only the files that I touched and get the latest versions of those files, but some of the files contain changes from both my changesets and his changesets (and mine are after his).

So what I really want is a way to merge specific changesets into my workspace (without pciking up all the previous changes) to get back to the state I was in before I did "Get Latest".  Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's no good way to do this.  Fortunately, I had another branch that represented the changes I wanted (I had only merged my changes I wanted into it).  It didn't feel right to just copy the whole tree over my working tree, so I used WinMerge to identify the files that were different and copied just those files over (after a cursory look to confirm that it was a file that included my changes -- there were a few files generated by Visual Studio that were different just because they were in a different path).

So I guess the general solution would be to create a branch in TFS, merge everything you want into it, get a local copy, then copy the results into your workspace.  That does leave a mess in TFS, though (how do you completely remove the dummy branch?)  Fortunately the branch I had was one we really wanted to keep (we have a build branch separate from teh development branch).

Comment: I'd go with this option, make a branch based on a known good state, then cherrypick your changes you want to keep from it, but make sure you do not select "All changesets up to", just go to Merge, and select "Selected changesets", enter the changeset id's you want and voila (as long as none of your changesets depend on his changes you should be ok!).

Comment: Seems like a lot of overhead just to get a workspace to a particular state.  Is there a good way to clean up afterward -- completely remove the unneeded branch?  In my case the branch is needed, but I imagine there's a chance someone (maybe even myself in the future) might be in a similar situation without an existing branch at the right level, and I suspect a whole additional branch is going to leave some permanent overhead in the source control database.  Is that true?

Comment: Hm, it occurs to me that if you have *any* other branch that can be brought to the known good state, then you could merge into it without committing the changes yes?  So perhaps one could merge everything up to the known good state into Main, cherry pick merge into Main, copy the results into the working tree, then undo all pending changes.

Comment: Yeah, if you have a spare branch that you can bring up to date, you could do that, bring it up to your last working changeset, apply all your needed changesets.  Though I'd be happier working in a maintenance branch or something, since it would allow you to carry on working, checking things in and out, and you can merge back to the parent branch and sort out all the breaking changes properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this answers your question, but if you select "Get Specific Version..." then you can select a specific changeset.

Comment: The problem with that is it also gets all changesets prior to the specified changeset.

Comment: The only way that I can see around that is to take a copy for each of the three stages (i.e. one before any changes were made, one after the first set and one after the second set) and use a tool like beyond compare to manually weed out the changes that you want.